# retrieving a .CSV file previously created on device gives strange formatting

Tags: objective-c, csv, parse-platform

I'm sure it is a simple answer to a simple problem but i can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've got a .csv which is downloaded containing contact information from an ACT! database.

Like so...

```
PFQuery *jobsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Jobs"];
    [jobsQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"eWuJ6toJbO" block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            PFFile *csvFile = [object objectForKey:@"Contact"];
            [csvFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                if (!error) {

                    NSString *storePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"jobsfile.csv"];
                    [data writeToFile:storePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

                    uncompletedJobs = [[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:storePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]mutableCopy];

                    [self.table reloadData];
                    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

                    NSLog(@"Found on the database %@",uncompletedJobs);


                }else{

                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                   [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
                }
            }];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        }
    }];
}
```

After it is downloaded new contact information is added to it.

```
 NSMutableString *tmpString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@",[custArray objectAtIndex:0],[custArray objectAtIndex:1],[custArray objectAtIndex:2],[custArray objectAtIndex:3]]; //creating a string from the array.

 [uncompletedJobs addObject:tmpString]; //adding the new string to uncompletedJobs Array.
```

It is then uploaded to the server

```
-(void)createCSV {


    NSMutableString *csv = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",uncompletedJobs];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES); //Saving to documnets folder.
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newContacts.csv"]; //Save Name.

    NSError *error;

    BOOL res = [csv writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; //Has it saved successfully? BOOL.

    if (!res) {

        NSLog(@"Error %@ while writing to file %@", [error localizedDescription], filePath );
    }else{

        NSLog(@"No error creating save file! uploading...");

        [self upload];
    }
}

- (NSString *)getPath {

    NSString *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                   (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    return [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newContacts.csv"];
}

-(void)upload {

    NSString *SavedDataPath = [self getPath];

    NSString *path = SavedDataPath;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"newContacts.csv" data:data];

    NSLog(@"raw data we are uploading = \"%@\"", data);

    PFQuery *jobsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Jobs"];

    [jobsQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"eWuJ6toJbO" block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        object[@"Contact"] = file;

        [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {

               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Sending!"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error Report: %@ %@",error, error.userInfo] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"I've taken note" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

            }else{

                NSLog(@"Upload Complete, Hoorah!");

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Complete!"
                                                            message:@"You've successfully uploaded a new customer to the database." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];


                customerDropdown.hidden = YES;

            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Originally when the data was downloaded and put into uncompletedJobs the output looked like this...

```
( 
"Company,Contact,Address 1,Address 2,Address 3,City,County,Postcode,",
"Company,Contact,Address 1,Address 2,Address 3,City,County,Postcode,",
"New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,",

)
```

When the data is then downloaded from the server again back at step one (containing the new data added to the .csv) the formatting then looks like this. If more data is then saved, uploaded and re-downloaded it gets progressively worse.

```
(
    "(",
        "    \"Company,Contact,Address 1,Address 2,Address 3,City,County,Postcode\",",
        "    \"Company,Contact,Address 1,Address 2,Address 3,City,County,Postcode\",",
        "    \"New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data\",",
    ")"
)

)
   "(",
        "    \"(\",",
        "    \"    \\\"Company,Contact,Address 1,Address 2,Address 3,City,County,Postcode\\\",\",",
        "    \"    \\\"Company,Contact,Address 1,Address 2,Address 3,City,County,Postcode\\\",\",",
        "    \"New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data,New Data\",",
        "    \")\",",
    ")"
)
```

The data seems correctly formatted when it goes, but when it returns and is parsed there is something wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's hard to say without testing but I think I have an answer.

```
NSMutableString *csv = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",uncompletedJobs];
```

uncompletedJobs is an array, so your string (csv) will be like :

"(
    \"object0\",
    \"object1\",
    \"object2\"
    )"

If you dont parse that well and add it to your .csv, it becomes worst and worst...

Therefore you need to loop thru the array and add the individual string your NSMutableString.